# Visual Studio Code - Output in the External Shell (Not Integrated)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to start to use the visual studio code to learn the python. What I want to do is when I run for the code like Print ("Hello World"), I wants to appear it at the external shell - pop up cmd ( not at the integrated terminal at below ). Before I install python and its extension on visual studio code, the output seems to appear like that. It is my first trying and testing so I don't know what exactly make it look like that. so what should I do to make my code output can be appeared at the external pop up shell.

Comment: This is a feature of VSC. You don't have to switch programs to see the output of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in **User Settings.json**(Ctrl+,), then every time you **Run without Debugging**(Ctrl+F5), there will be an external terminal displayed and results in it.

```
"launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Python: Current File",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${file}",
                "console": "externalTerminal",
            }
        ],
    }
```

Actually the above are configurations we can set in [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations), which is for debugging. The default key-value should be `"console": "integratedTerminal"`. We change it to `externalTerminal` to achieve our goals. However the `launch.json` only works for the current project, so we put it in **User Settings** to make it effective globally.

Besides the green button in the upper right corner is meant to run python file in **integrated** Terminal and this setting won't change its function.

Comment: Thanks buddy, this solved and helped me. very much appreciated.

Comment: @echo, Glad to know my answer helped you, it's appreciated that you can mark it as "accepted". please have a look at [Tour-Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.
2. Search `@command:workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole`
3. Add your keyboard shortcut.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.
5. Add:

```
"terminal.external.linuxExec": "xterm",
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh",
```

Replace `xterm` for your favourite terminal and `zsh` for your favourite shell.

6. Press the keyboard shortcut you chose for the external terminal.

#### Output

1. Use the extension `Code Runner`;
2. Add to `settings.json`:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": 
{
        "c": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o filename && ./$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o filename && ./$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "python": "cd $dir && python $fileName",
        "python2": "cd $dir && python2 $filename"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just go to the directory where the Python file is Eg `C:/users/<user name>/<path to python file>` and run using `py <python file name>.py`

Example if your Python file is named `test.py` run it with `py test.py`. However if you can't find the path to your file, just go to the `File Explorer` and at around the left area in the input box, type in `cmd` (command prompt) and it will open it for you.

Comment: glad i could help :)